# Div color background error

Tags: html, css, flexbox

the issue I am having is that when I change my browser size to tablet and mobile my quotes and testimonials named Jerry and Michelle go outside of the color background which makes me think that they aren't nested correctly. However, I looked at it and I believe it should work but somehow it isn't. The easiest way to see this since I just isolated this code and my whole site isn't pushing it out of the background colored box, is if you make the code snippet full-sized and put the browser to the smallest width. You will see the quotes outside of the colored box. If anyone could spot the issue and let me know it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```css
#colorbk{
 background-color: #1DA0A3;
}

.container {
     display: flex;
    background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width:1700px;            
    margin: 0 auto;      
}

#qwrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 margin:10px;
 background-color:#1DA0A3;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
 margin:0;
 
}

#lighticon{
 padding-bottom:30px;
}

#jerry{
 width:400px;
 
 
}
#michelle{
 width:400px;
 
}


.italic{
font-style:italic;

}

.right{
 float:right;
 
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .row {
    
  }
 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
#qwrapper{
  justify-content: space-around;
   margin:10px;
 }
  }
```

```html
<div id="colorbk">

   <div class="container">
<div id="qwrapper">

<h3 id="michelle" class="row" ><div class="italic">"She always thinks of her clients."</div>
<br>
<div class="right" id="connect">-Michelle Houle Conn. FSE</div>
</h3>

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" class="row" alt="" id="lighticon"/>

<h3 id="jerry" class="row"><div class="italic">"Very smart, creative person, problem solver."</div>
<br>
 <div class="right">-Jerry Nygard C2P</div>

</h3>
</div>
</div>  
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: try making `#jerry` and `#michelle` responsively width'ed by using something like `#jerry,#michelle{width:100%;max-width:400px;}`

Comment: I applied that to my quotes and it is responsive and looks good up until mobile. In mobile Jerry's tagline is still kicked out of the box. @haxxxton

Comment: its looking ok on my end, can you clarify with an image please http://imgur.com/SnHEub2

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/d3PBj  Here's the image @haxxton

Comment: ＠Cakers you change the image to something else, if it was the previous one it should work.

Comment: Ah, this is a result of how `float`s function, you should probably either switch to using `text-align:right` or employ a [clearfix technique](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to the parent box

Comment: @haxxton this still doesn't work. Here's a Jsfiddle to show the updated changes with the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply solve the issue by removing `width:400px` from inner texts:

```
#jerry{
    /*width:400px;*/
}

#michelle{
    /*width:400px;*/
}
```

as in following snippet:

```css
#colorbk{
 background-color: #1DA0A3;
}

.container {
     display: flex;
    background-color: #1DA0A3;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width:1700px;            
    margin: 0 auto;      
}

#qwrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 margin:10px;
 background-color:#1DA0A3;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
 margin:0;
 
}

#lighticon{
 padding-bottom:30px;
}

#jerry{
 /*width:400px;*/
}

#michelle{
 /*width:400px;*/
}


.italic{
font-style:italic;

}

.right{
 float:right;
 
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .row {
    
  }
 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
#qwrapper{
  justify-content: space-around;
   margin:10px;
 }
  }
```

```html
<div id="colorbk">

   <div class="container">
<div id="qwrapper">

<h3 id="michelle" class="row" ><div class="italic">"She always thinks of her clients."</div>
<br>
<div class="right" id="connect">-Michelle Houle Conn. FSE</div>
</h3>

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" class="row" alt="" id="lighticon"/>

<h3 id="jerry" class="row"><div class="italic">"Very smart, creative person, problem solver."</div>
<br>
 <div class="right">-Jerry Nygard C2P</div>

</h3>
</div>
</div>  
 </div>
```

**Edit:**

for [your jsFiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/1), i modify it as following:

[jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/2](http://%20jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/2)

remove `height:100px` from `.row` class. also as the last icon has set its size with that row class, i add `width:100px` to it in `#lighticon` css:

```
.row {
  flex: 0 auto;
  /*height: 100px;*/
    margin:0; 
}

#lighticon{
  width:100px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't work. Here's a Jsfiddle to show the updated changes with the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/81d8trag/1/

Comment: Yup! I have added the image to the page @S.Serp

Comment: Yes, I did add it to the post it is right after the snippet. @S.Serp

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are fixing the width of

```
#jerry {
    width: 400px;
}

#michelle {
    width: 400px;
}
```

to 400px, so no matter how large or small your screen size is, it is fixed to 400px. if you want to make it responsive you have to use %.

Comment: I see your point and I'll change them to percentages but it still kicks them outside the box